# Pandas fill np.nan issue

Tags: python, windows, pandas

## Environment

- Windows 8.1
- python 3.5
- pandas

## What I want to do

To fill `np.nan` in `pandas.DataFrame` columns according to the following rules:

1. if the values are numeric, fill `np.nan` with the mean of the rest of the values.
2. if the values are not numeric, fill `np.nan` with the mode of the rest of the values.

## Issue

Following code doesn't seem to be working.

```
# build DataFrame
dfna = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,5), columns=list('ABCDE'))
dfna['F'] = [random.choice(list('abcdefghijkf')) for i in range(100)]
dfna[::20] = np.nan

# filling np.nan
def filler(x):
    if type(x) == 'numeric':
        x.fillna(x.mean())
    else:
        x.fillna(x.mode())

dfna.apply(filler)
```

I know why this fails. It's because type(x) returns `'pandas.core.series.Series'`. However, how do I achieve my goal? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

## solutions (4/29/2016)

### solution1

```
numeric_cols = dfna._get_numeric_data().columns.tolist()
nonnumeric_cols = [c for c in dfna if c not in numeric_cols]

dfna_num = dfna.loc[:, numeric_cols] = \
    dfna[numeric_cols].apply(lambda col: col.fillna(col.mean()))

dfna_nonnum = dfna.loc[:, nonnumeric_cols] = \
    dfna[nonnumeric_cols].apply(lambda col: col.fillna(col.value_counts()[0]))

pd.concat([dfna_num, dfna_nonnum], axis=1)
```

### solution2

```
for col in dfna.columns:
    if dfna[col].dtype != 'object':
        dfna[col].fillna(dfna[col].mean(),inplace=True)
    else:
        dfna[col].fillna(dfna[col].mode(), inplace=True)
```

Thanks, folks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first separate your numeric and non-numeric columns.

```
numeric_cols = dfna._get_numeric_data().columns.tolist()
nonnumeric_cols = [c for c in dfna if c not in numeric_cols]
```

You then assign the mean to the numeric ones, and use `value_counts` to get the item that occurs most frequently (or the first of such items if there is a tie).

```
dfna.loc[:, numeric_cols] = \
    dfna[numeric_cols].apply(lambda col: col.fillna(col.mean()))

dfna.loc[:, nonnumeric_cols] = \
    dfna[nonnumeric_cols].apply(lambda col: col.fillna(col.value_counts().head(1).index[0]))
```

Or you can use this function:

```
def filler(series):
    avg = series._get_numeric_data().mean()
    series.fillna(series.mode().values[0] if np.isnan(avg) else avg, inplace=True)

dfna.apply(filler)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. but the latter solution didn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

Something on top of my head:

```
for col in dfna.columns:
    if dfna[col].dtype != 'object':
        dfna[col].fillna(dfna[col].mean(),inplace=True)
    else:
        dfna[col].fillna(dfna[col].mode(), inplace=True)
```

The `inplace=True` directly edits it inside the frame (no copy).

Note however that if there are no common elements in the `non-numeric` columns, the `mode` returns `[]`, so the original values stays the same.